# Qt: How to know if slot was called by signal-slot mechanism by calling the signal like a function

Tags: qt, qt-signals, qt-slot

Inside a slot I check the [`QObject::sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) but now I want to call this slot directly like a function.

Can I know how this slot was called inside of the slot? Either by signal-slot mechanism or simply by calling the slot like a function?

Comment: Put the code into another function which has a `bool fromSignal`, and call this other function from your slot with `true`, and call it directly with `false` elsewhere.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That'd make a fine answer, I think, better than the current ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `sender()` in both cases. In case of the slot being called via a signal/slot mechanism the sender will return a pointer while when called as a method it will return null pointer.

Simple example:

```
class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void signal();

public slots:
    void slot() { qDebug() << sender(); }
};
```

And the use:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Test test;
    Test test2;

    QObject::connect(&test, &Test::signal, &test2, &Test::slot);

    test.signal(); //slot is caled by signal
    test2.slot(); //slot is called as method directly

    return a.exec();
}
```

And the output:

> Test(0xa8e8aff5b0)
>
> QObject(0x0)

Comment: sender is not null when it is called as a method

Comment: It is even stated in the documentation: "Returns a pointer to the object that sent the signal, if called in a slot activated by a signal; otherwise it returns 0. The pointer is valid only during the execution of the slot that calls this function from this object's thread context." http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender

Comment: The "if called in a slot" here presumably means "if called during the activation of a slot".  Which means if he calls the slot directly "as a function" but from another slot invoked by a signal, the directly called slot will observe a non-null return value. But that is not what he was looking for. And it renders your solution flawed if not invalid.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a default parameter to your slot:

   ```
   public slots:
       void slot(bool calledBySignal = true);
   ```
2. Set the parameter to false when calling the slot directly:

   ```
   void MyClass::method()
   {
       [...]
       slot(false);
       [...]
   }
   ```
3. Leave the `connect()` calls as they are; don't add a bool parameter to the signals, nor change `SLOT(slot())` to `SLOT(slot(bool))`.

Disadvantage: It's easy to forget setting the parameter.

If your slot doesn't need to be public, because `connect()`ing to it is handled from inside the class only, you should make it private and add a wrapper method that's to be called instead, but still you'll need some discipline when calling it from inside the class. Johannes' suggestion would solve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea to distinguish between direct function call vs. Signal/Slot-invocation:

Use the method int QObject::senderSignalIndex() const and check for -1

```
if(QObject::senderSignalIndex() == -1){
    //called directly as a function
} else {
    // invoked via Signal/SLot mechanism
}
```

> Returns the meta-method index of the signal that called the currently executing slot, which is a member of the class returned by sender(). If called outside of a slot activated by a signal, -1 is returned.

[see Qt 4.8 documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#senderSignalIndex)

This looks like a clean way to distinguish and there is no chance of getting into trouble with a null-pointer in contrast to using `QObject * QObject::sender() const`.

Regards,
Felix